# How to get the list of SparkListeners in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I get the list of current added listeners. Similar to the streamings listeners `spark.streams.listListeners`.
I have found the following but in scala that attribute is not found.
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16382/files.
`sc.listenerBus.listeners.contains(sparkListener1)`. There is no listeners attirbute in scala.